# Oracle - Difference between Soft parse and Hard parse

Tags: oracle, plsql

From [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_hard_vs_soft_parse_parsing.htm) explanation in askTom, the difference between hard parse and soft parse is,

> Loading into shared pool - The SQL source code is loaded into RAM for
>   parsing. (the "hard" parse step)

This step is not done in soft parse.

Now, say we execute the following block:

```
DECLARE
v_emp_no number;
BEGIN
 v_emp_no := 6675;
 SELECT EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_NO = v_emp_no;  --STEP 1

  v_emp_no := 1234;
 SELECT EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_NO = v_emp_no;   --STEP 2

END;
```

Both the statements(step 1 and step 2) are exactly identical, and using bind variables(host variable and bind variables are practically same in PLSQL)
So there should be a soft parse here.

BUT

the sql source code for the queries cannot be same here, as essentially

```
STEP 1 = SELECT EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_NO = 6675; 
STEP 2 = SELECT EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_NO = 1234;
```

So how does oracle do a soft parse at STEP 2, as essentially the query and source code should be different from STEP 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has three "virtual machines", SQL one, PL/SQL one and JVM. In your case two VMs have to interact.

Look into v$sql_plan to see what exactly is passed to SQL parser from PL/SQL. The PL/SQL variable will be replaced with bind var. placeholder.

You can also trace the session. In the trace file you will see one PARSE and two executions of the CURSOR. So most probably there will be only one hard parse and no soft parse.
You can re-execute parsed statement with different bind variables many times.

PS: you should use `SELECT INTO` when executing SQL from PL/SQL.

Comment: `PS: you should use SELECT INTO when executing SQL from PL/SQL` :Yes my query was just for the sake of example.

So you mean to say that there will not even be a soft parse in this case?

Comment: @Arnab - yes. In the trace file you would see: PARSE CURSOR #1, EXECUTE CURSOR #1 (bind variable value 6675), EXECUTE CURSOR #1 (bind variable value 12345). The soft parse would take place when you executed the same block from another session.

Answer (score 4):

No, the query in both cases uses a bind variable:

```
SELECT EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_NO = :B1
```

So Oracle can use the same parsed query for both, just binding the different values.

If you can select from system view [V$SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2113.htm) then you can see this for yourself:

```
SQL> select sql_text from v$sql where sql_text like 'SELECT EMP_NAME%';

SQL_TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_NO = :B1
```